# How to share token information between two different domain

Tags: javascript

I have a wordpress site with login authentication. In wordpress, we have another link for separate angular application. This angular application again has to authenticate user.

When user logs in from wordpress site, he can jump to another application via link available in wordpress site. I am tring to share token (local storage, cookies) created at time of login. But not able to. As these two application resides on two different domain. So now how i can share token from one domain to another domain? Any tricks or solution to it.

Comment: It doesn't sound possible, the way you describe it. If have dev control over both apps, you could look at something like SAML to provide SSO, or implement an OAuth server or something. Just trying to share tokens doesn't sound like it would work.

Comment: @Starscream1984, Thanks for repling. I would have gone for OAuth server. But client wants to have something like this. I restricted with clent approach. Is there any tricks to do so?